# Find, search and compare values and differences between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem, how to create a query.

In SQL Server I have tables Company (with IDcomp), Cap, Founder, Adress... Tables Cap, Founder and Address are connected with Company on IDcomp. Tables Cap, Founder and Address have attribute `country`. What I'd like to do is, to check if there is any address country that is not in Cap or reverse for specific IDcomp. In both tables can be several different countries. My SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.IDcomp, c.compName, cap.country, a.country
FROM Company AS C
    JOIN Adress AS a ON(a.IDcomp = c.IDcomp AND a.base = '02') -- founder address
    JOIN Capital AS cap ON(cap.IDcomp = a.IDcomp)
    JOIN Founder AS F ON(f.IDcomp = a.IDcomp)
WHERE c.obl = '103'
    AND (a.zap_num = f.zap_num AND f.IDcomp = c.IDcomp)
    AND (cap.country != a.country)-- AND nu.country = u.country)
    AND a.country IS NOT NULL
    AND cap.country IS NOT NULL
    AND f.country IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY c.IDcomp
```

With this query I don't get right result, where there are 2 or more countries in founder and cap that are the same. What should I do?

Comment: Can you edit your question with sample data and desired results?

Comment: Even better, add DDL + DML so that we can try to run it ourselves.

Comment: Hello. Here is example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2bcdc/1). The last three result should not be on the list, because there are tha same countries in table Adress and Capital.
I did edit some of the code, because i did some mistakes with letters.

Comment: Any idea how to write code?